# WMI change name property

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I have a legacy application which works on `Windows 7` and `Windows 2003 Server` but is not working on `2012 R2`, Getting OS non-compatible error. When I try to capture the `procmon`, got to know it executing the `WMI` query `Select Name from Win32_OperatingSystem` and validates the name `property;`

1. Is it possible to change the name property on `Win32_OperatingSystem` class? on further reading on `Technet`, I got to know its a read only property.
2. Tried running the application in compatible mode, no luck :(
3. Any solution to overcome such a problem.

Comment: How about contacting application vendor? If that's not possible anymore, you could use a VM or patch the application so that it doesn't care about the OS version compare.

Comment: If a piece of software is incompatible with a "current" OS you should contact the vendor instead of trying to change these kind of properties to be honest. I love coding my way around things but it stops at a certain level.

Comment: Its a legacy application and there are no developer currently available to update the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides shims to cope with this kind of compatibility issue.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644(v=ws.10).aspx